# Need help in understanding this SQL query

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please help me in understanding this SQL code?
This is what is actually confusing me more - END = G.CODE

```
SELECT something, something
FROM ABCD A
JOIN GHIJ G ON 
    CASE    
        WHEN A.CODE = 'not available' THEN 'NA_CODE'
        ELSE A.CODE END = G.CODE
                   LEFT JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.ID = A.ID
                   WHERE P.ID IS NULL;
GO
```

Thanks
Isha

Comment: @RanchiRhino Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at properly formatted code you will understand it.

```
CASE WHEN A.CODE = 'not available' THEN 'NA_CODE' ELSE A.CODE END = G.CODE
```

consider the join clause like

```
 B.XYZ = G.CODE
```

Where `B.XYZ` is a case statement for manipulating joining column `A.CODE` for values 'not available' to `'NA_CODE'` so that it could match same value in `G.CODE`.
Except the value 'not available' everything is fine so the case statement only manipulates 'not available' to `'NA_CODE'`, so that join clause could match it with value inside `G.CODE`.

Look for case statement for more details.

Hope you understood.

Here :-

`B.XYZ =[CASE WHEN A.CODE = 'not available' THEN 'NA_CODE' ELSE A.CODE END]`

Comment: I think you are struggling with case statement it has a start with CASE and ends with END inbetween CASE....END every calucaltion comes out as a single column values.

Comment: million thanks to you man. I really had been struggling with this code from days. You are a savior :)

Comment: sorry one more question here.. when we do this left join, its just going to return us the records that matches these two conditions   P.ID = A.ID
                   and P.ID IS NULL; ??

Comment: yes correct, based on Following statement  `
TABLE1 Left Join TABLE2` => everything from `TABLE1` and matching from `TABLE2`

Comment: so in my case PRODUCT P is the TABLE2 right and GHIJ G is TABLE1? sorry im not too much familiar with sql thats the reason you see so many stupid questions.. confused because we have 3 tables here in my query

Comment: your PRODUCT P is TABLE 1. it will return records for P.ID = A.ID and all other records from PRODUCT P

Comment: shouldnt it be the TABLE 2 since statement says LEFT JOIN PRODUCT P?

Answer (score 1):

There is more you need to understand in this query.

You got a good answer for the "CASE ... END = G.CODE" - indeed, the point there is that "END" does not exist by itself, it is the last key word in the CASE expression syntax.

With that out of the way, note that your query will return no rows. This is because at the end you have

```
...LEFT JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.ID = A.ID
   WHERE P.ID IS NULL
```

Rows with P.ID "IS NULL" are not returned in the LEFT JOIN - only rows where P.ID = A.ID and rows where A.ID is NULL are returned. (When P.ID is NULL, the equality with A.ID is UNKNOWN, so the row is NOT returned.)

Comment: hey, thanks i got your point, but we are trying to insert new records from table A into table P so when there are new records in table A that are not already in table P this query should work right?      My query actually is   INSERT INTO A, SELECT SOMETHING SOMETHING...........

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your actual code; I am inclined to say "NO" since the select is evaluated before you get to any "insert" part. Post your entire INSERT statement if you need help with it.

Comment: INSERT INTO PRODUCT  
GLOBALID  
TYPE  
BLOCK  
COLOR  
CODE 
      SELECT  
     A.GLOBALID  
     A.TYPE  
          A.BLOCK  
          A.COLOR  
          G.CODE  
FROM ABCD A  
JOIN GHIJ G ON   
    CASE      
        WHEN A.CODE = 'not available' THEN 'NA_CODE'  
        ELSE A.CODE END = G.CODE  
                   LEFT JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.ID = A.ID  
                   WHERE P.ID IS NULL;  
GO